# How to return a set of nested results in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document structure like this:

```
[{
  id: XXX,
  title: 'A Title',
  variations: [
    {attribute: 'value', created_at: date},
    ...
  ]
 },
 ...
]
```

I'd like to search on the main document AND the nested parts, and then return a set of results where the nested `variation` parts are the top level so that a document could appear twice or more in the results if the `variations` are a match. I'd also like these results returned in `created_at` order. Is this "pivoting"?

e.g. search may be "All variations where `attribute` contains X and `title` like Y, ordered by `variation.created_at`"

I could create a separate index where the variations are the top level document, but then how would I include the actual top level doc without a huge amount of duplicated data?

### Actual examples:

https://www.muchbetteradventures.com/adventures/discover/ is a search based on the top level document being a holiday.

https://www.muchbetteradventures.com/adventures/timeline/ is the holidays' indivudual departures, i.e. a holiday can appear more than once in this listing since it may have more than one departure.

At the moment, the first page is generated with ES, the second is a DB query. We want to add in more of the ES search and speed into the second view.

Comment: well just taking a look at your problem i think parent child relationship elasticsearch will be the way to go for you. This will definitely give you more flexible approach to fetch the related documents at same level with querying the parent and child document at same time. take a look see if this suits i can help more https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the info you provided i tried putting together a minimum working [solution](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html) for you based on parent child relationship and you want fetch only the nested/child documents based on attribute values both in parent and child documents.

```
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "parent_document" : {
      "properties": {
        "title" : {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "child_document" : {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "parent_document"
      },
      "properties": {
        "attribute" : {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST index_name/parent_document
{
  "title" : "document three"
}
```

**Note:**  pass parent query params as the ID of parent document created to whom you want to associate this child to.

```
POST index_name/child_document?parent=AV1PoQdYA2MvrCm0IPxT
{
        "attribute": "value9",
        "created_at": "2017-08-08"
}

POST index_name/child_document/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "parent_document",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "title": {
                                            "value": "document"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "attribute": {
                            "value": "value9"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will get you started.
Thanks